# Failure to run VBS script with task scheduler

Tags: vbscript, windows-10, scheduled-tasks, taskscheduler

we have this vbs script we use to update certain documents with SyncToy.

This is the script as it is currently written:

```
'--------------------------------------------------

Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

sFilePath = chr(34) & "C:\Program Files\SyncToy 2.1\SyncToyCmd.exe" & 
chr(34) & "-R"

iRC = oShell.Run(sFilePath, 0, True)

' Return with the same errorlevel as the batch file had
Wscript.Quit iRC


'---------------------------------------------------
```

I didn't write this script, and I have very little experience with scripting.

I have a task set up in task scheduler that runs this script anytime the device connects to a network. The script should run SyncToy and then synchronize the folder pair that is set up. I have tried running the script through command prompt with the cscript command but nothing happens as far as I can tell. At least the folders aren't syncing.

The script is running on a Windows 10 pro tablet

I have verified that the task is indeed running when it is supposed to. I'm just not sure if it is an issue with the way the script is written or if the task settings need to be changed. Is there anything wrong with the script as far as you can tell?

I was unsure whether to post this here or over in serverfault. If this doesn't belong here please move the question over to serverfault

Update: I've verified that this isn't a problem with the script. This problem apparently arose only after the update from SyncToy 2.0 to 2.1.

Thanks Guys.

Comment: You need a space inside `"-R"` - it should look like `" -R"`- @Tommy shows the line correctly - if that's the way it is in your code please edit and update your question. Also -if you are doing this in a scheduled task, you need to specify the `start in folder`  - it's a weird VBS issue with Windows Tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a error with the `sFilePath` lines.
First, I don't know if this was originaly on a single line but it should (or add "_" before changing line).

Then, this `(...)&  >"-R"` would not work. The ">" symbole is outside the quotes and generate a error.

If you want to execute this command: `"C:\Program Files\SyncToy 2.1\SyncToyCmd.exe" -R`,
this is the way to do this:

```
sFilePath = chr(34) & "C:\Program Files\SyncToy 2.1\SyncToyCmd.exe" & chr(34) &  " -R"
```

You can also add `msgbox sFilePath` to show a popup with the value of `sFilePath`.
To test/run the script, you just need to double-click on it.

Comment: The > character wasn't supposed to be there and the sFilePath line was originally all one line in the script. The sFilePath line in the script looks to be the same as yours. Is it possible that the SyncToyCmd.exe doesn't do what the old tech thought it did? As far as I can tell this script only starts the program, but doesn't actually start the sync. Which is what we wanted.

Comment: The script should run the program as if you double-click on it. To test this, double-click on the "SyncToyCmd.exe". If it doesn't work, it mean that the program is no more compatibled.

Comment: Hi, I was just wondering, is having quotations around the -R proper syntax for an argument? wouldn't you leave the -R un-quoted and then have the name of the desired folder pair in quotes after it?

Comment: Ok, I'm going to mark this as the answer. I've verified that the script is correct thanks to you. It's SyncToy 2.1 that just doesn't do anything when running the SyncToyCmd.exe program. When running the program through CMD it will even show the Sync I want running. But it will end after fractions of a second. I'm going to try using SyncToy 2.0 to see if it's just a version issue. Thanks

Comment: Great, 
About your question, it won't work. Imagine that you write the comand in a  comand line. What would be the comand? Then you have to send this comand (as a string variable) to a shell object in vbs. Everything outside the quote MUST be a vbs comand. Else, it will crash